# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter

I'm a new in Flutter. 
I have a problem with a calling future method in constructor. I create method, that return a classes with widgets depends of selected item. The problem is that I need to call this method several times, the first time to build the body, the second time to update the body on tap. But I see error "type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'"  If I add the type of void instead Future, it will be executed once to create a body. 
Code snippets:

```
class DataPageState extends State<DataPage> {
....
    _tables() async {
    if (selectedValue == "a") {
      return DataA();
    }
    if (selectedValue == "b") {
      return DataB();
    }
    if (selectedValue == "c") {
      return DataC();
    }
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(...
body: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
          _tables(), //errors this  //I need to call method this
         ... new Stack(children: <Widget>[
              AnimatedContainer(...),
                      InkWell(onTap: () => setState(
                      () {
                        _tables(); //and this
                      },
                    ),)])...}
```

Comment: do you want to add widget on click ?

Answer (score 0):

You `_tables()` function should return some Widget. If you want to build Widget using some async call you can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

_tables() can not be async. you have to return `Widget` instead of `Future<widget>`.

Here is the demo of of how to add widget on click.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Widget _add = Container();

  test() {
    _add = Text("datcdsvcdsvsvdjvkjdsvsa");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: Text("Press"),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  test();
                });
              },
            ),
            _add,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But how I can call it again in "OnTap" event?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should just edit the function `_tables` to make it synchronous.
like this:

```dart
Widget _tables() {
  if (selectedValue == "a") {
    return DataA();
  }
  if (selectedValue == "b") {
    return DataB();
  }
  if (selectedValue == "c") {
    return DataC();
  }
}
```

Nowever, If you have some reason to make _tables asyncronous, then do this:



Tables is a type Future. You need a `futureBuilder` for this.

```dart
Stack(children: <Widget>[
  FutureBuilder<Widget>(
    future: _tables(),
    builder: (BuildContext _, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasError) { // Error
        return const MyErrorWidget(); // You will have to create this widget
      } else if(!(snapshot.hasData)) { // Loading
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }/ Loaded without any errors
      return snapshot.data; // The widget that was returned;
    },
  ),
  // the rest of the widgets in the Stack
]);
```

Now this won't solve the problem. You will have to add a return type to `_tables()`.
so do this

```dart
Future<Widget> _tables() async {
```